# Prettify CiviCRM pages

Tags: wordpress, templates

Total newbie.  Don't know what I don't know...

I am trying Civi with WP.  Tried with Joomla.  I loved Drupal in another life.  :-)

Is there a simple way to make the output pages for Civi (like events, registration, etc.) prettier - more in line with the types of pages you see in a typical website?  I guess I'm spoiled with all these builders these days.

Like a theme of some sort?  Or an addon?

The presentation here is gorgeous:  https://www.cividesk.com/civicrm/event/register?id=611&reset=1

But (1) I think that's Drupal and (2) I think it's custom.

I just can't seem to find a way (short of modifying .tpl files) to make Civi look a bit better.

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: You can create your own event registration pages using HTML and profiles.

You can use the APIs if you want to create different administration pages

Comment: For wordpress maybe https://github.com/mattwire/civicrm-haystacktheme ?

Comment: can you guys add above as Answer so Marse can 'accept'?

Comment: Marse - it would be polite to let the above know they were helpful by +1 their answer below and accepting the best one

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own event registration pages using HTML and profiles. You can use the APIs if you want to create different administration pages

Answer (score 1):

With Drupal you can use Webform and [CiviCRM Webform Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm). These give you a lot of flexibility in designing forms that look more current. CSS is simple with this since it is built into Webform. Example of a contribution page-- https://secure.radiusinternational.org/give-financially